# How to get the index of values inside key in a map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple map with 2 keys in each index and for the second key I have more than one value, my question is how can I access each value inside the key separately.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> cards = [
{
  "intro": "6-WEEK BICEPS TRAINING PROGRAM",
  "desc":
      "You’ll train your biceps twice a week, blasting them on Monday with a workout that targets them as your primary muscle group."
},
{
  "intro": "HERE’S YOUR WEEKLY TRAINING SPLIT:",
  "desc": ['Monday: Biceps, triceps, and abs', 'Tuesday: Legs'],

},
```

];

So for example cards[1]['desc']. now I want to access 'Tuesday: Legs'

PS: when I try cards[1]['desc'][2] i get this error
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  Try defining the operator '[]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `[1]` to the end of your existing statement to result in `cards[1]['desc'][1]`.

`cards[1]['desc']` returns a `List` with 2 elements: `'Monday: Biceps, triceps, and abs'` & `'Tuesday: Legs'`. Using `[index]` syntax allow you to access the members of the `List` based on their index.

Additionally, `List<Map<String, Object>>` is not the correct type for what you are storing. Your `Map` contains `String` keys with all `String` objects so far. Change it to `List<Map<String, String>>` to reflect this.

If you need to store more than just `Strings` in the `Map` do `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, replacing `Object` with `dynamic`.

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: You have misdefined your `Map` in the initializer. I will edit my answer.